# Kubernetes - Service configuration runs but not exposed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, opensearch-dashboards

I have an opensearch app which I want to expose via a service so it can communicate with the opensearch-dashboard app I got.
when I open a shell in the pod I see that the opensearch server works properly.

when I run to extract the url :

```sh
cat /etc/hosts
```

I get:

```
opensearch-master-headless-0.opensearch-master-headless.search.svc.cluster.local
```

if I run this in the same pod, I get 200 response.:

```
curl -XGET http://opensearch-master-headless-0.opensearch-master-headless.search.svc.cluster.local:9200 -u 'admin:admin' --insecure
```

if I run it from the dashboard pod in the same namespace it says its not resolved:

```
curl -XGET http://opensearch-master-headless-0.opensearch-master-headless.search.svc.cluster.local:9200 -u 'admin:admin' --insecure
```

my service.yml

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.global.appName }} --- evaluates to opensearch
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.namespace }} --- evaluates to search
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  ports:
    - name: "http"
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9200
    - name: "transport"
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9300
---
```

But, If I use the opensearch's pod IP Address:

```sh
curl -XGET http://<IP-ADDRESS>:9200 -u 'admin:admin' --inse

cure
```

this works from the opensearch pod

- I'm using argocd to deploy, when I deploy the opensearch app, it doesnt raises any errors on my service configuration

Comment: You should be able to use the Service's name and namespace as described in [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) in the Kubernetes documentation; `http://opensearch.search.svc.cluster.local:9200`.

Comment: Did @DavidMaze's suggestion helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can access via type `NodePort` of `Service`

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.global.appName }} --- evaluates to opensearch
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.namespace }} --- evaluates to search
spec:
  type: NodePort
  clusterIP: None
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  ports:
    - name: "http"
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9200
      nodePort: 30920
    - name: "transport"
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9300
      nodePort: 30930
---
```

Then, call via IP of Node k8s
(get IP of Node k8s by command `kubectl get node -o wide` - at field `INTERNAL-IP`)

`curl -XGET http://<INTERNAL-IP>:30920 -u 'admin:admin' --insecure`

Comment: thank you, but my problem is that I don't want to use the IP, that works for me. I want to use the DNS name so it'll persist over deployments.

Comment: So, you can use ingress in k8s to do this.